# Facebook page in iphone application

Tags: iphone, facebook-page

I have used facebook-iphone-sdk to implement sharing functionality.
Now, How can I integrate Facebook page in my Iphone application. Is it possible?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Facebook Graph API calls through the SDK to make calls against your page.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

As an example in your call to post, say to the news feed, you'll just put the pageId or page name like:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"pageid/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Anyone can get read access to most of the Graph API calls for a page as noted in the docs, so you shouldn't even need to authenticate the user to simply display some data from the page in your app.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Can I put page URL in webview so users can interact with it?

Comment: Yup that should work as well.  The above would allow you to code deep integration with your app.  The UIWebView option will work as well to display the web version of the page.  You may want to look at using the http://touch.facebook.com/xyz URL so you get the mobile touch formatted version of the page.  The only downfall to this method is that users, I'm pretty sure, won't get single sign on, so they'll need to type in their username and password into the webview before they can interact with the pages.